# Use Clang with MSVC 2010

Tags: visual-c++, clang

First of all, I want to ask if Clang compiler is better than MSVC's default compiler? And how can I use Clang with MSVC? For example, I write code in MSVC then when I hit Build, it call Clang to build the project.

Comment: Consider using CMake with both GNU Makefile backend and a Visual Studio backend.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

https://github.com/ishani/ClangVSx

AddIn for Visual Studio 2010 that allows use of the Clang C/C++ compiler in place of MSVC++. Translates VC project and build settings into gcc-friendly command line arguments, along with existing platform tools (MSVC Linker, Librarian, RC) to complete the build chain.

Comment: Looks like it's a nice tool. I will check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Using clang compiler on Windows is still considered to be in *experimental* state. However, some progress has been made recently. As I [answered similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487931/llvm-c-ide-for-windows/19084342#19084342):

> LLVM provides [Windows snapshot builds](http://llvm.org/builds/) - a clang toolset for Visual Studio as Windows installer. Currently it should integrate with Visual Studio 2010, 2012 and 2013. More information can be found on LLVM's blog post *[A path forward for an LLVM toolchain on Windows](http://blog.llvm.org/2013/09/a-path-forward-for-llvm-toolchain-on.html)*.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a "makefile project" to have Visual Studio invoke a makefile (or any command-line process) when you tell it to build.

I've done this before to get MSVC's nice source navigation for non-Windows embedded projects.

The drawback is that you have to manually keep the makefile in sync with the files in the project (or vice-versa depending on how you want to look at it) - generally not a huge problem.

Comment: Makefile is a big road block. Is there any other way to workaround?

Comment: Can you give more detail on why using a makefile is a roadblock?  I'd guess that any other workaround would involve more effort, unless you can find that someone has built a 'CLang plugin' for Visual Studio.

Comment: Having to write and maintain a Makefile consumes a lot of time. It become even more serious since I tend to develop apps using agile aproach, which means I change/add/delete files very frequently. Eventually, I will end up spending most of my time on the Makefile. It also requires tools to be installed on computer, like Cygwin.

Comment: @Quang: Visual C++ comes with a variant of make (called `nmake.exe`). You're right that setting up and maintaining a makefile-based build can be complicated; that depends on how complicated your project is overall. But, I suspect that that complexity (or lack of complexity) would be reflected in a VS project/solution-based build as well. Generally, once the makefile build is initially set up, adding or removing files from a build is a matter of adding or removing a filename from a text file. Of course, you have a much better idea than I do what might be involved for your situation.